# Unable to re-prod and fix LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-XXXXXX crash

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

Firebase shows many crash reports of Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException from `LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-xxxxxx`.

[Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/hbb20/0ffa975df9e36117e4560b5e0de5fe7b) does not show any line from my code either which leaves me clueless. Seems like it's compose internal issue and I tried to re-prod the issue by scrolling and over-scrolling the lazy column but that didn't work.

Did anyone else face the issue that can help me fixing the issue?

Comment: Add your code where you are using LazyList to understand the problem

Comment: The problem is I have many lazy lists in the app. Not sure which one it's happening on because reports are not very clear about it.